# Are all wound removal spells ritual casting?

Tags: spells, healing, rituals, ars-magica-5

All of the the creo corpus spells that remove wounds appear to be ritual.  Is this true of all spells that remove wounds from a character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, otherwise the wound would reappear at the end of the spell's duration.

Your two options for healing magic are as follows:

1. You have to follow the laws of magic which says that you can't
   create permanent things without the use of vis, if you cast a ritual
   spell with a momentary duration, at the moment the spell is cast.
   The healing is done and that wound is gone forever.
2. You cast a non-ritual spell to close a wound, i.e. one that doesn't
   mandate the consumption of vis. Now if you cast a healing spell with
   a month duration, the wound will be healed as long as the spell
   lasts. The second the spell ends, the wound comes back.

So while formulaic casting can be momentary, and you can use a creo corpus spell to momentary heal a wound... A second later, the wound will be back. The only way to make a spell effect last is a ritual spell of momentary duration.

Comment: Can formulaic casting be momentary duration?  E.g. close light wound as a formulaic spell?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Can you elaborate on your answer, and support it by citing evidence?

Comment: Your two options for healing magic are as follows: 1) You have to follow the laws of magic which says that you can't create permanent things without the use of vis, if you cast a ritual spell with a momentary duration, at the momment the spell is cast. The healing is done and that wound is gone forever. 2) You cast a non-ritual spell to close a wound, i.e. one that doesn't mandate the consumption of vis. Now if you cast a healing spell with a month duration the wound will be heal as long as the spell lasts. The second the spell ends  the wound comes back.

Comment: so while formulaic casting can be momentary, and you can use a creo corpus spell to momentary heal a wound...a second later the wound will be back. The only way to make a spell effect last is a ritual spell of momentary duration,

Comment: Thank you for the explanations.  I think this illuminates a point about permanency that I'm confused about, but that is probably the subject of another question altogether.